# get value of selected item and change the list on second dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to change the second dropdown list when an item is selected on 1st dropdown

```
$output_body = '<select>';
$accounts = $service->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts("~all");
  foreach($accounts['items'] as $item) {
 $output_body .= sprintf('<option value="%d">%s</option>', $item['id'], $item['name']);
    }
    $output_body .= '</select>';
```

so when i select an item from above dropdown list it should store value of selected item in variable and that variable will be used here which i believe update the dropdown list

```
$webproperties = $service->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties("var here");
    foreach($webproperties['items'] as $item) {
        $output_prop .= sprintf('<option value="">%s</option>', $item['name']);
    }
    $output_prop .= '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example for cascading dropdowns in jQuery. (populating one based on the selection of another)

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var productsSelect = $('#productId');
        productsSelect.attr('disabled', true);
        $('#categoryId').change(function () {
            var categoryId = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON('/GetProducts/' + categoryId, function (products) {
                productsSelect.attr('disabled', false);
                productsSelect.empty();
                productsSelect.append(
                        $('<option/>')
                            .attr('value', '')
                            .text('-- Select Product --'));
                $.each(products, function (index, product) {
                    productsSelect.append(
                        $('<option/>')
                            .attr('value', product.ProductId)
                            .text(product.ProductName)
                    );
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice in my opinion to be able to use event bubbling on the parent element in conjunction with a html data element, submit the request to your php controller and assign the option data back to your view, but I'm not sure if you have the mvc framework to support this or not...

```
 window.addEvent('domready', function() {
        $('parent_option_list_container').addEvent('click:relay(a)', function(e, ele) {
    if (ele.hasClass('some_option_in_the_list')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selected = ele.get('data-option-value');

                    var request = new Request({
        method: 'POST',
        url : '/form_controller/option_select_toggle_function/' + selected,

        }).send();
    }
```

}